# Error in OpenCv in Java in Depth of image?

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvPoint;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvScalar;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvSeq;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.CvCapture;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvGetSize;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    IplImage img = cvLoadImage("images.png");
    IplImage hsvimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    IplImage grayimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

    cvCvtColor(img,hsvimg,CV_BGR2HSV);
    cvCvtColor(img,grayimg,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cvShowImage("Original", img);
    cvShowImage("HSV", hsvimg);
    cvShowImage("GRAY", grayimg);
    cvWaitKey();

    cvSaveImage("Original.jpg",img);

}

}
```

My "IPL_DEPTH_8U, CV_BGR2HSV" is not working, I took this code from [YOUTUBE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkC55xDREKE&list=PLhf6FZHr6APTqMuhpU3eJCOAAgqCeTA3Y&index=3) this tutorial I tried many times but this is not working please help me.

Comment: what specific error you are getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 IPL_DEPTH_8U cannot be resolved to a variable
 IPL_DEPTH_8U cannot be resolved to a variable
 CV_BGR2HSV cannot be resolved to a variable
 CV_BGR2GRAY cannot be resolved to a variable

 at main.main(main.java:49)

Comment: Please use this library https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv or this https://github.com/opencv/opencv .

Comment: I am using now.. bt nothing happened